# Google Earth/Maps aerials via arc2earth producing cuts in PDF output

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, aerial-photography, arc2earth

I just purchased a month of arc2earth. They provide Google imagery backgrounds with great resolution and display fine in ArcMap but after exporting to PDF they have these triangular cuts as seen here:

[image: arc2earth PDF output]

Anyone ever worked with arc2earth before and seen this? 
Please don't tell me there is no fixing this and the cuts in the PDF are arc2earth's way around Google's legal issues.

Comment: Try exporting to another format - JPEG - does the same thing happen?

Comment: I had to take a break from it... i will try exporting to JPEG and other formats when i return.

Comment: According to James Fee's GIS blog there should not be any Google legal issues (since May 2011) using their imagery for background in ArcGIS... i'll be taking another look at possible export to pdf settings causing these cuts in a little bit http://spatiallyadjusted.com/2011/05/13/latest-version-of-arc2earth-allows-google-earth-imagery-in-arcmap-legally/

Comment: Mapperz, i tried exporting to almost every other output (tiff, jpg, etc.) with the same problem occurring when data driven pages is in use, once data driven pages is taken out of the equation it exports fine... i posted the problem on arc2earth's forum but there appears to be very little activity there.... any thoughts on what changes to the export settings in arcmap might solve this problem? I have to be able to use data driven pages with this 200 page map book.

Answer (score 3):

this issue is related to using (some) projections, multiple map rotations (like during your auto map book production) and higher dpi output (like in a pdf). We're working on a fix that will hopefully be available in the next release.

For the record here as well, producing a map book like this is only allowed if the product is not resold. (more info here: http://www.arc2earth.com/faq/)

Comment: Straight from the guy who wrote the Arc2Earth software.  I don't believe there's a better authority than this.  How about accepting this as an answer?